# How to select all nested values at a particular level in a json structure in a JSONB type column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb, json-path

In a postgresql database, I have a table with 2 columns:

Column1 is of type VARCHAR and contains multiple rows of ids in this format: ID1123312

Column2 is of type JSONB and contains multiple rows of jsons which have this structure:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "a1": "2022-01-01",
            "a2": "2026-01-31",
            "a3": 1
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
            "b1": "J",
            "b2": "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9"
        }
    ],
    "c": [
        {
            "c1-1": "2021-02-01",
            "c1-2": "2021-01-01"
        },
        {
            "c2-1": "2021-04-01",
            "c2-2": "2021-03-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to build a SELECT statement to return **only** the values of the b2 property from all rows of Column2. If it has just one row, then just '1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9'. If it has multiple rows, any value that it finds inside each jsonb inside each row.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2 ? (@ == "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9")')
```

SELECT * returns the whole row of the table but I don't know how to instruct it to return just whatever value the b2 property contains (nested inside the json from the row) .

Comment: `SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2 ? (@ == "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9")') FROM t` maybe? Did you even look at the link I posted on your previous question https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I did look at the link but I just didn't see this function - I kept scrolling down from that point in the document where the link opened and I did not see this, because it was above : jsonb_path_query_first - This is the info I lacked. Please post an answer and I will accept it. Additionally could you tell me what kind of wild card  I could use instead of the hardcoded value, so that it returns any value at that specific path? I tried jsonb_path_query_first(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2 ? (@ == *)') FROM t ; but that does not work. It seems * is not the wildcard I need.

Comment: Just remove the predicate? `SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2') FROM t`

Comment: Yes, that does it, but it still leaves the leading and trailing quotes in the results: Like: "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9" ; Do you know any trick to remove those?

Comment: How many objects are there in the `b` array, and how do you want to show if there are multiple?

Comment: In b array there is always just one element to my knowledge. I guess you are referring to my last comment from the initial question which you pointed out. There I meant that 
`SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2') FROM t WHERE jsonb_path_exists(t.jsonColumn, '$.b[*].b2 ? (@ == "1231342138adc2fehj3j21321321321kjk1423j32k9")') ` returns just the value I specify after  `@ ==` ; I meant to ask what is the syntax for adding more than one value after  `@ ==` in order to query for 2 or more values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only have a single object in each `b` array. Therefore you odn't actually need a path query, you can use normal JSON accessors.

`->` retrieves a value as `json(b)` and `->>` retrieves it as text

```sql
SELECT t.jsonColumn->'b'->0->>'b2'
FROM t
WHERE t.jsonColumn->'b'->0->>'b2' IN ('Value1', 'Value2');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v4X9L_Gg)